# convert html table to csv using pandas python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-tableextract

That's My code is working fine.

```
import pandas as pd
html_data = """<table id="example" class="table table-hover dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info">
                            <thead>
                            <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" aria-label="Start Date/Time: activate to sort column ascending">Start Date/Time</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="End Date/Time: activate to sort column ascending">End Date/Time</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Caller Name: activate to sort column ascending">Caller Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Caller Number: activate to sort column ascending">Caller Number</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Callee: activate to sort column ascending">Callee</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Used Mins.: activate to sort column ascending">Used Mins.</th><th class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="File">File</th></tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">2020-11-27 12:50:23</td><td>2020-11-27 12:51:04</td><td>ABC 3</td><td>7111</td><td>923333222</td><td>1</td><td class=" text-center"><audio controls="">
        <source src="../record_files_out/3/2020/oc_1.wav.wav" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="../record_files_out/358/2020-11-27/oc_1934553_358.wav.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio></td></tr></tbody>
                        </table>
"""
print(pd.read_html(html_data)[0].to_csv(index=False, header=True))
```

Here is output

```
2020-11-27 12:50:23,2020-11-27 12:51:04,ABC 3,7111,923333222,1,Your browser does not support the audio element.
```

But I Want to extract

```
../record_files_out/3/2020/oc_1.wav.wav
```

Instead of this

```
Your browser does not support the audio element.
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to check out this recommended option:

```
# Importing the required modules  
import os 
import sys 
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
   
path = 'html.html'
   
# empty list 
data = [] 
   
# for getting the header from 
# the HTML file 
list_header = [] 
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path),'html.parser') 
header = soup.find_all("table")[0].find("tr") 
  
for items in header: 
    try: 
        list_header.append(items.get_text()) 
    except: 
        continue
  
# for getting the data  
HTML_data = soup.find_all("table")[0].find_all("tr")[1:] 
  
for element in HTML_data: 
    sub_data = [] 
    for sub_element in element: 
        try: 
            sub_data.append(sub_element.get_text()) 
        except: 
            continue
    data.append(sub_data) 
  
# Storing the data into Pandas 
# DataFrame  
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = list_header) 
   
# Converting Pandas DataFrame 
# into CSV file 
dataFrame.to_csv('Geeks.csv')
```

Comment: Same problem, I want to extract also "../record_files_out/3/2020/oc_1.wav.wav"